# How to show Total No. of post author In blogger

Tags: blogger

I want to show total no. of post author  in blogger with ajax get method bellow is my code.

```
<div id='show'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
    url: "/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script",
    type: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data) {
        var totalposts = data.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t;
        document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = "<div class='totalposts'>" + totalposts + "</div>";
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an array of authors `["Ali","Bassam","Mohamed"]`, loop through posts and filter by author. Use `max-results=9999` to include maximum number of posts.

```
<div id='show'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
    url: "/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&max-results=9999",
    type: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data) {
        var authors = ["Ali","Bassam","Mohamed"];
        var postNum = new Array(authors.length).fill(0);
        var result = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < data.feed.entry.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < authors.length; j++) {
                if (data.feed.entry[i].author[0].name.$t == authors[j]) {
                    ++postNum[j];
                }
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < authors.length; i++) {
            result += authors[i] + " : " + postNum[i] + "<br>";
        }
        document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = "<div class='totalposts'>" + result + "</div>";
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: author: Bassam 57    author: MOHAMED 70